# Find the transfer function G(s)

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a set of equations from which I have to find the transfer function $G\left(s\right)=\frac{y\left(s\right)}{u\left(s\right)}$

I am given:

$0.15\cdot \frac{d^2\left(x+l\theta \right)}{dt^2}+1.4715\sin \left(\theta \right)=0$

and

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+0.15\frac{d\left(x+\theta \right)}{dt^2}+0.5\frac{dx}{dt}=u$

I am also given that $y=x+\theta $

Basically, by simplifying, I get:

$\frac{dx^2}{dt}+0.5\frac{dx}{dt}-1.4715\theta =u$

and

$0.15\frac{d\theta ^2}{dt}+1.4715\theta +0.15\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}=0$

How do I go about finding the transfer function?  $x$ and $\theta$ are in the same equation. Do I simply transfer them both as $X(s)$ and $\theta(s)$?

Comment: Yes, but I always get an $s^4$ in the denominator of the transfer function. I think I should get a simpler solution

Comment: $s^4$? Why do you get $s^4$?

Comment: When replacing $\theta$ with respect to $x$, I get $s^4$ in the denominator